# Importing motion capture data to Blender rig

Tags: import, motion-capture

I would like to use "c3d" for animation on Blender. Does anyone know about how to do it?

I'm sorry for my poor English. Actually, I'd like to import the c3d to Blender, and I want to know how to apply them to the rig. For example, in Softimage, I was able to import the c3d via the "motor", it will be used to rig. Such usage is it possible in Blender?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the file format c3d? Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: This is what you want: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30838/7777