# Can I set my pose position like the new rest position?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I would like to move my armature from pose mode to another pose (a random one) and set the position I create like the new rest position. Is there a way in order to achieve this goal?

My armature is deforming a mesh so I want to deform the mesh too.

This is my mesh and its relative REST POSITION:

[image: Mesh and its relative rest position]

I want to change and set a new REST POSITION and I follow your advice; 
I change my armature in pose mode and then click on Apply pose as Rest Pose:

[image: Changed armature in pose mode]

The result is this one:

[image: End result]

The armature resets the rest pose like I wanted, while the mesh - I can't understand why - comes back to the original position (the one set by the old rest pose).

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: If none of these solutions work for your scenario, you might want to try **Pose Library**, set a default pose and add a new pose, that's it. It should be noticed that this is not actually a default pose, but you could apply the pose instead, or even another rest pose.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Apply the armature modifier - armature in rest pose doesn't deform anything, so we need also a mesh to match the new rest pose.
2. Pose > *Apply Pose as Rest Pose*. This will set current pose as the rest pose. It sets only bones poses - constraints or custom properties in complicated or badly designed rigs might make the rig act weird with bones in different rest state!
3. Add the armature modifier back.

Comment: Seems to be more complicated than necessary, why do we have to apply the modifier first, it should work without this?

Comment: And what about rigify? It's definitely too complicated or badly designed. How to make it right for a rigify rig? Should I re-pose the source metarig and then just rebuild, or there is another way?

Comment: @Mechanic Yes, exactly like that. You do that on metarig and then generate the complicated rig again. It's the reason why complicated rigs need to be generated with scripts and not build by hand. If it didn't had this functionality to generate from metarig, it would be indeed "badly designed rig".

Comment: @Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny, thank you. I've played a bit with different layers of the rig, and eventually I regenerated it in the new pose. Thanks gods there is a snap tool to easily re-pose the metarig against the already posed actual one.

Comment: Where is "Apply the armature modifier"? How do I change the mesh to the pose position?

Comment: @AaronFranke In object modifiers: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/index.html

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that you cannot apply a modifier to a mesh that has SHAPE KEYS.   So if your are using (for example) a converted Daz3d rig with morphs and associated shape keys, you cannot use this trick (unless you want to sacrifice all your morphs and associated shape keys.)

Answer (score 4):

Apply the pose as rest pose.  Remember this will naff up any animations using the previous rest pose.  There will be a warning of such in the system console.

Applying the armature modifier will deform the mesh to match a pose.

[image]

Comment: i edit my quesion after i use your method. Please check it. I can't understand why doesn't work

Comment: How do you apply the armature modifier? I can only see where to apply a pose as rest pose, but this results in the bones being outside the mesh.

Answer (score 3):

Apply pose as Rest Position only sets armature position, there is a sophisticated way to do this without any plugin by a hack, this [blog](https://nixart.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/modifying-the-rest-pose-in-blender/) saved me several hours of modelling.

> -It copies armature modifier in `Object Mode`.
>
> -Then applies one of the modifier, and voila. :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I've been using the [Cats Blender plugin](https://github.com/michaeldegroot/cats-blender-plugin) which has a built-in button to do this. It handles both mesh deformation and changing the pose bones at the same time.

[image]

Once you have Cats installed, you can open this menu by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>, then "CATS", then you can click "Apply as Rest Pose". Note that if you wish to pose the object further, you need to go into "Object Data" Context -> "Skeleton" -> select "Pose Position".

Answer (score 1):

Hey this one will simply help you a lot dude! Simply click on armature then click the human form Icon under it it indicates the rest position! Good luck ! [image]

Comment: That just switches between the 'Pose' position and the 'Rest' position, it doesn't *apply* the 'Pose' position *as* the 'Rest' pose.