# Making the "Object mode" pose and the Edit mode" pose the same?

Tags: armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

I don't know the correct language to use, but I've got a rigged model and I've positioned it how I want it to be in Pose mode. Everything looks great in Object mode, but when I go to Edit mode my model snaps back to its default resting position. Which makes it very difficult edit it.

I'd like to set the pose to be the same in all modes.

I'm going to 3D print this rather than render or animate it.

Answer (score 2):

In the modifier you can enable the *On Cage* option and, in *Edit* mode, the mesh will appear as it is when posed (even though the gizmos will stay at the non-modified position, which is unfortunate imho):

[image]

If you want your mesh to definitely take the *Pose* position and don't need anymore armature, apply the *Armature* modifier.

If you want to keep the armature and you want it to keep the new *Rest* position as well, follow the method described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49768/can-i-set-my-pose-position-like-the-new-rest-position) by Jaroslav: Apply the *Armature* modifier, select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Pose as Rest Pose*, and give back an *Armature* modifier to your object with the armature as *Object*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click both icons in the root modifier not the single first one