# Mesh animated using vertex groups has unknown offset floating the bones

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-groups

Attached is an animated gif that demonstrates my issue, I have attempted the solution proposed here:
[Can I set my pose position like the new rest position?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49768/can-i-set-my-pose-position-like-the-new-rest-position)

However this is not working for me, any suggestions/ideas for troubleshooting this?

Basically I have assigned this groin cloth to some specific vertex groups named after a pair of upper and lower bones. All other vertex groups for the other bones appear to be aligned correctly, however this groin cloth only is not aligning.

[image: animation]

(The first view is showing the rest bones aligned, during pose mode however the groin cloth you'll see is hovering over the bones)

Comment: Have you tried to remove these vertices from all groups then reassign them to the desired vertex group(s) manually or through the vertex groups list?

Comment: Any difference between rest and pose is going to be due to bone constraints, drivers, or bone transforms.  The rig is probably what's important here.  The answer you linked is not necessarily appropriate for bones that have constraints or drivers.  We'd need a file to tell you what's going on.