# Put Armature Rest Position to T pose

Tags: python, animation, armature

I have an animated armature found in the .blend file found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nx8xsk4z0pavaxx/ArmatureToTpose.blend?dl=0) where I want to set the rest position to T pose so I can parent a T pose easily with it. How this can be done?

Comment: Something like http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53981/15543 ?

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for your comment. I've checked them and I'm kinda lost with the steps as they are not numbered. I've updated my question and added a .blend file which contains my armature so you can have a better look and idea of what I mean. Like what I'm trying and want to do is to put it in Tpose and set the Tpose as rest position to be able to parent my character mesh after that.

Comment: Do you have that rig in another file in the Tpose?.  The rate determining step here is going to be posing it.  With another rig we could use it with constraints to bake a new animation.

Comment: @batFINGER I've added a Tpose and followed your steps in your other answer as Ricardo showed, and it looks good. Yes, I have made a T-pose in my updated file found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/aujsase0ymgue7j/ArmatureToTpose2.blend?dl=0 so if you switch to rest Position you will find the armature in Tpose (I tried to make it look as good as possible), so can I use it for this as the rest pose for all the other armatures I have?

Comment: @batFINGER Also you will find that the mesh is doesn't look good, kinda twisted and during the animation it get's ugly, I'm not sure why? I constructed this armature from your answer to the .c3d to .bvh question found here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30835/convert-a-c3d-and-trc-files-to-bvh I feel it's because of the bone roll value?

Comment: as you suggested in the c3dToBvh answer, I've used `DAMPED_TRACK` as Jerryno suggested. And the mesh looks a little bit better than using `TRACK_TO` using `con = pb.constraints.new('DAMPED_TRACK')` 
  `con.target = bpy.data.objects.get(pb.name)`
  `con.track_axis = 'TRACK_Y'`
  `con.influence = 1`   but still looks not good.

Comment: A screenshot when using `TRACK_TO` at frame 70 can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbqw9xj3jzxur05/TRACK_TOFrame70twisted.PNG?dl=0 and a screenshot when using `DAMPED_TRACK` at frame 70 can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/lryeqaxxa6h7518/DAMPED_TRACKFrame70twisted.PNG?dl=0 . The mesh I'm using can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzl5k98zkdhlw4y/human_mesh_good.dae?dl=0 Could you please have a look and let me know what you think?

Comment: @batFINGER and this is the original file of the .c3d points https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnzfszkplhyd8dv/c3d.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the rest pose in Pose Mode Editor and using the menu Pose > Apply [Ctrl+A] > Apply Pose as Rest Pose.

HOWEVER, you will destroy your animation: this "rest" pose is the base for the animation data, all transformations are made using this bone orientation.

**EDIT:**

As @batFINGER wrote above (about a similar thread: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53981/15543), I got the procedure working (with Blender 2.78a) in the following way:

1. Pose your model to the new rest pose (without keyframing);
2. Run the "script 1" (retarget_pose.py) to generate UI buttons (under Properties Editor > Object Data Tab);
3. Click "New Rest Pose to Rig" (it will duplicate the bones - inside the same armature - with the new rest pose);
4. Click "BVH action to new restpose rig" (it will correct every keyframe of the animation);
5. Manually delete the original bones (as I could not make the "script 2" - the one posted in the thread - work);

Comment: Well, I know this and I know the issue, I was wondering how someone can help me with it to work correctly :)

Comment: I got @batfinger 's suggestion working. Edited my aswer above. 
I didn't use a second armature as suggested. Also, for many rigs like you have, it would be useful to got the "script 2" working or create another script to automatically delete the older bones.
Still, you will have a lot of work by manually "restposing" each of those rigs.

Comment: Think I have the latest of all those ops in  https://github.com/batFINGER/batFINGER-blender-addons/tree/master/mocap_madness which is very much a WIP.. Had some recent queries on this from BA and have looked into a new method using copy transform constraints (world) and baking action from that.  Theoretically could be done with matrix math from old pose to new pose too... but....

Comment: @batFINGER I've now created a Tpose as rest position for one armature using your steps. Could you please advise how I can apply this Tpose rest position to other armatures? I posted it in another question to make this question more specific to applying rest position, while the other one to be specific for applying the saved rest position to other armatures. Question can be found here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67806/apply-saved-rest-position-to-different-armatures

Comment: @Tak I believe you can only do that if you have the same number of bones and the bones have the same name on both armatures. Is that the case? Doesn't it work to copy and paste the pose - then manually continue with the process described here?

Comment: @RicardoRoehe yes it has the same number of bones with same names. But how I can copy/paste the Tpose to another bvh?