# How can I make a BVH armature with no discernable rest position into a T-Pose?

Tags: armature, bvh

I'm trying to work with some mocap data.  I found [this BVH](https://github.com/BandaiNamcoResearchInc/Bandai-Namco-Research-Motiondataset/blob/master/dataset/Bandai-Namco-Research-Motiondataset-1/data/dataset-1_walk_chimpira_001.bvh) and imported it.

It walks great, but it has no t-pose.  When I go into edit mode, the armature doesn't resemble anything at all.

How can I get a t-pose out of this?  I've found other questions about changing a rest position ([Put Armature Rest Position to T pose](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67474/put-armature-rest-position-to-t-pose)), but this seems to be beyond that scope.  I can't figure out a way to animate this at all.

[image]

Comment: Suspect I'll find the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72190/33487