# Apply pose as rest position keeping previous frame

Tags: animation, pose-mode

Using Blender 2.9.

I have an animated armature with only two frames. The armature at first frame matches the rest position, while the second has two bones rotated. Now, I'm trying to achieve a possibly unsupported operation.

I want to set second's frame pose as rest position, without causing the same effects on the first frame as well (ultimately, to prevent loosing that position). I understand this isn't a straightforward goal because poses are "forward"-relative to the first (you may correct me if I'm wrong). In fact, when I try to do it, Blender throws the exception "Actions on armature will be destroyed by new rest pose", and replicates the rested pose to the first frame as well.

Is there a way to achieve this, even if it involves reversing the animation so that the original second frame becomes the absolute source of the transforms for further animation frames? If there is a compatible addon with latest version which exactly allows to do this, that'd be fine.

Note when I apply that pose as rest position, I can't restore the old first frame's position anymore, even when I copy-paste pose from another Blender instance with the file without these temporary changes.

[image]

(The model is about hands for a viewmodel)

Thanks.

Comment: See method used here.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53981/15543  Dupe the rig and change rest pose on dupe. Join back to original. Copy transfroms via constraint  of  each bone of joined rig back to its original.  The rig can now be used to convert animations between a number of rest poses.

Comment: Is the linked script from that post dead or it requires registration?

Comment: Prob dead. Updated the needed part of script in other question, it was however not the link I meant to post, rather this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72190/15543

Comment: I tried your updated method and it seemed not to work. This is what I did:

1. Downgraded to Blender 2.8 to make sure.
2. Saved both scripts inside Blender, for convenience (New Rest Pose to Rig and BVH Action to New Rest Pose Rig).
3. Selected armature in Object Mode with the second frame selected (my interest Pose). Applied my armature modifier (needed), and executed first script (**worked**).
4. Executed the second script, so new armature is created but the old first frame animation is lost as well (shows newly Rested Pose too instead).

Would you like to try it yourself? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally [this addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/copy_attributes.html) (with pose mode features) along the usage of a helper bone exactly helped me to solve my broader [kind of problem](https://blenderartists.org/t/changing-inherit-rotation-during-animation/630402). My original question only involved a harder way.