# Mesh deformation during animation

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I have an animated armature in my .blend file found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ig9dwfczn2zcei/RollProblem.blend?dl=0). I parented a mesh to my armature while in rest pose and it's good, once the animation starts the mesh start twisting. I wonder how I can avoid this unwanted twists deforming my mesh during animation. If anyone could please help me solve this issue as I will be doing it automated using Python as I have many armatures to parent with the same mesh, so it needs to be possible to be handled by python scripting.

Comment: Just looking at your head bone in pose mode, (with local axis) the animation looks like it is z axis facing forward.  Your rest pose isn't.... resulting  in the twisting.

Comment: @batFINGER thank you very much for your assistance. So could you please advise how it could be fixed? and how to avoid this from happening when building my armature please?

Comment: Not sure there's an easy answer to this.   Could try posing a new Tpose taking note of bone alignment (eg as noted in previous comment z forward for head bone, you'll notice all the bones from origin down look dodgy based on action poses) Then try something like in [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72190/15543)

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you. The armature was constructed using the method you provided here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49295/2517 do you think there is a way to fix this while the armature is constructed through that script?

Comment: Is the Tpose on frame 0 created from the C3D data?

Comment: @batFINGER Yes, it is already in the c3d data.

Comment: The issue is in the pose vs the rest pose on however you made the action.  Given it's pretty much a human rig, I'd be tempted to use rigify rig (or similar), edit meta-rig to match your rig dimensions, generate, then animate with constraints to c3d empties (using the  IK bones works pretty well ).   Will be a bit of a PITA to tweak, but only needs to be done once, and can be used on other c3d files with the same subject.